# Reverting to open-source Radeon driver shows low resolution graphics

Tags: drivers, resolution, radeon, fglrx, gpu

I have tried to install the fglrx proprietary drivers for my Radeon 9000 (RV250) graphics card. This didn't work so I tried to revert to the open-source version based on this page [(purge fglrx)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection#Problem:_Need_to_purge_-fglrx) to uninstall fglrx and install the open-source version. It seems like I can't change the resolution from the very low 640 x 480 and the catalyst icons are still visible in the settings manager. I am running Xubuntu 14.04. There was no problem prior to the attempt at installing the proprietary version. The following command outputs may help:

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV250 [Radeon 9000 Series] [1002:4966] (rev 01)

dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'
.....
```

no output is produced after the last command.

Comment: So would rolling back to the previous driver be ok? do you need this one for any specific reason?

Comment: If rolling back to the driver prior to the fglrx driver, yes. I don't need a proprietory driver at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seem to have done the trick. It seems like some packages were not included in the uninstall in the above link I provided.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```